# Combine two maven project

Tags: maven, spring-mvc

I Implemented two maven project each using spring MVC, Hibernate, Jax-RS service. they have separate configuration, database, controllers, models, services.

I need to combine both the project in such a way that one is work as parent and other should be its child and can access parent services.

Comment: You don't need the parent/child relationship, unless you want to hve the "parent" defining the version of the components to use. TO have the child be able to access parent classes, just add the parent as a dependency. You should read some tutorial on the net about multi module maven project, it's quite the basics

Answer (score 1):

If you want to share configuration among projects, you can use a parent pom.
If you want to combine two projects as subprojects of one larger one, you can use modules. Both concepts are described in

https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-pom.html#Project_Inheritance_vs_Project_Aggregation

If you want to access classes from project in another project, add a dependency in the dependencies section of your pom.